# list index out of range when running Selenium

Tags: list, selenium, loops

I am new in coding. I have a question. I tried to run selenium for scraping data with 13 pages in total. Unfortunately, after page 13, the loop is still running, and I don't know how to stop the loop. This is the error: list index out of range when running Selenium, please I need your help. Thank you !

This is the code that I make

```
txt = driver

.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="searchResultsCount"]').text
print(txt)
print(txt.split{' '))

def result_status(driver):
    txt = driver.find_e1ement(By.XPATH,'//*{@id="searchResultsCount"]').text
    current = txt.sp1it(' ')[1]
    end = txt.sp1it(' ')[3]
    return current, end, driver

def next_page(driver):
    pg_elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'page-link') #<a href="#page-274"
    nxt_elem = [x for x in pg_elems if x.text == 'Next‘][@]
    nxt_elem.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    return driver

driver = next_page(driver)

results_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Put it all together (From Matt)

# Get current resuLts
current, end, driver = result_status(driver)

#Loop through resuLts

i=0
while current != end:
    i += 1
    if i%2 == 0:
        results = driver.find_element(By.ID,'searchResultsArea')
        results_html = results.get_attribute('innerHTHL')
        temp = pd.read_html(results_html)[0]
        results_df = pd.concat([results_df,temp], ignore_index=True)
        results_df.to_csv("results.csv", index=False)

    #Check Status
        current, end, driver = result_status(driver)
        print(current,'|',end='')

        #Go to next page
        driver = next_page(driver)
    if i == 660:
        break

results = driver.find_e1ement(By.ID,'overSearchResults')
results_html = results.get_attribute('innerHTML')
df = pd.read_htm1(results_html
```

And this is the error

```
IndexError      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Loca1\Temp/ipykernel_37444/2741504647.py in <module>

     21
     22        #Go to next page
---> 23        driver = next_page(driver)
     24    it i == 690:
     25        break
```

Comment: Show the code you wrote for better suggestions/answers.
One wild guess to your error would be keep a counter and break the loop when the counter reaches 13

Comment: Hi Thank you for your suggestion @AnandGautam

Comment: I put the codes as a jpg picture, but next time I would write down the codes.. I already make a break in the loop, but it didn't work out

Comment: Is it possible to share the website link?